# Duplicate Key Error Index : insertOne MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm getting error

```
duplicate key error index: my.own.$_id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('57d2c4857c137b20e40c633f')
```

this ObjectId is from first insertOne() but second insertOne() command fails can anybody help me in this.
Just learning Java Driver MongoDB

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.HelperNodeList;
import org.bson.Document;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static com.mongodb.MongoCredential.*;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Creating Credential Parameters
        //MongoCredential credential = createScramSha1Credential("root","my","root".toCharArray());
        //MongoClient to connect
        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient();
        MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("my");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("own");
        Document document = new Document("x",1).append("y",3);
        collection.insertOne(document);
        collection.insertOne(document.append("z",3));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should specify the language/driver and also the `import`s/`using`s/... . Probably the problem is reusing the `document` object.

Comment: @GáborBakos I can't insert another document using append ??

Comment: @GáborBakos code updated

Comment: Have a Look at the _id of the document after the first insert. I assume it is set. And therefore you cannot insert the second document with the same id. Just try to set the _id to null before second insert.

Answer (score 2):

you inserted a document using insertOne method, now you are trying to use the same method to perform update operations which is wrong.

```
{ collection.updateOne(document.append("z",3)); }
```

you have to use the updateOne method to updated the document. the insertOne actually try to re-insert the document to your mongo collection and hence you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use insertOne actually try to re-insert the document to your mongo collection and hence you get the error.

now, if u want **another collection** means,
collection.insertOne(document);
collection.insertOne(document.append("z",3)).remove(_id));

if u want **same Collection** means,
 collection.updateOne(document.append("z",3))